# Optimizing Tax Revenue In City Builder Game

Tags: optimization, economics

I am currently developing a city builder game that incorporates a tax revenue system, allowing players to redeem their city's tax revenue every 24 hours. I want to create a mathematical model for tax collection that optimizes the players' experience from a game design perspective. The game targets a wide demographic of players, ranging from young children to adults, so I aim to make the system intuitive and engaging without discouraging players. Additionally, I want to incorporate a progression curve into the model.

Some of the variables that need to be considered in the tax revenue system include:

- Fixed tax rate (I am unsure about the appropriate range)
- Service coverage (fire, police, health stations)
- Average land value
- Population
- Players experience (level, xp)

I would appreciate guidance on where to start mathematically in order to develop this tax revenue model. How can I strike a balance between intuitiveness and complexity to ensure an enjoyable gaming experience for players of all ages?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the game development stack exchange?